# Making a jukebox, adding track list to list box from .text file

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

Right I am relatively new to programming and I am currently in the middle of my second assignment which is to create a jukebox using arrays, list boxes, media player, text box's, timers and menustrip. I have a number of text files that are laid out like this

```
2
Other
Big Bad John (1961) - Jimmy Dean.mp3
My Ding A Ling - Chuck Berry.mp3
```

The first line is the amount of tracks and the second is the genre of the tracks the rest is the actual tracks, what I need to do is display the tracks in a list box and when I use the scroll bar of the list box have it display the next set of tracks from the following genre.
The following is a small piece of my code,
I currently have some global's

```
public string MediaPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
public int NumberofGenre;
ListBox[] mediaLibrary;
```

and then I use the number of genre for the columns of the array if i have done it correctly.

```
private void JukeBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader inputStream = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2(1)\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Genre amount.txt");
        NumberofGenre = Convert.ToInt32(inputStream.ReadLine());
        mediaLibrary = new ListBox[NumberofGenre];
    }
```

If anyone can give me any help in displaying the tracks that are listed in my text file in my listbox, it would be much appreciated. It will likely require me to skip the first 2 lines as i only want to display the track names. I have spent a days going over lectures and the general internet and I am at a loss.

Comment: so what is the error? are you facing any problem?

Comment: There isn't a current error as I have removed my failed attempts, what I am trying to do is display the tracks that are listed in my text file in my listbox.

Comment: It's not very clear from your code if your ListBox[] array is referencing anything on the form.

Comment: if you are referring to the global, I have created new instances of it later on but I do not think it is correct.                  mediaLibrary[1] = new ListBox(); 
mediaLibrary[2] = new ListBox();
mediaLibrary[3] = new ListBox();

Comment: Global variables are usually a bad sign leading towards spaghetti code.  So, you have an array of ListBoxes.  From what you've shown us, these ListBoxes don't exist on a form anywhere, just in your memory array.  Also, you aren't showing us how you are *adding* any items to these ListBoxes.  My guess is that you probably only want one ListBox or a ListView control and add the song items to that one control - the control that placed on a form in the designer.

Comment: According to my assignment brief I need an array of listboxes, and I have used the global as it is the way my lecturer has done so in his small example of code. My GUI is set out with a text box to display a single genre at a time, underneath there is a listbox that should show the tracks in that genre shown in the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single file you would do these things:

- 1 read all lines into a string array
- 2 (optional) check if the total number of lines is lines1 + 1
- 3 (optional) show line2 in a label
- 4 for each remaining line add it to the listbox

note: line1 is lines[0] etc..

for a whole list of files repeat for each file and listbox.

Here is a starter:

```
1 - string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("firstFile.txt");
..
4 - for (int l = 2; l < lines.Length; l++) mediaLibrary[0].Items.Add(lines[l]);
```

(Don't worry about global variables; at your current level you probably don't even know how to create them. Your variables are class variables and **when used with care** perfectly OK..)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Will this display just the track names (lines after the genre) or will it display the whole file.

Comment: C# counting starts with 0. So the for loop skips the first two lines.

Comment: I receive the following error for the .Add . 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yup, I left out the `Items` property, sorry. See the edited code.

Comment: Im getting NullReferenceException was unhandled for mediaLibrary{0}Items.Add(lines[1]);

Comment: If necessary (and also if not!): Do use the debugger and find out if a) you have not created the listbox  mediaLibrary[0] (Um, watch those brackets not braces!) and/or b) you have misspelled the lines[l] for lines[1] (watch the letter  'l' and the digit'1'!). You must create those listboxes (and also somehow place them somewhere!) before you can fill them.

Comment: I have the ListBox[] mediaLibrary; as a global, is that creating it?

Comment: We are getting a bit carried away here. Comments are limited to a few responses.
`ListBox[] mediaLibrary;` is called the _declaration_. To actually create the individual listboxes they must be _instantiated_, either by a command like this: `for (int lb = 0; lb < numberOfGenres; lb++) mediaLibrary[lb] = new  ListBox();`or by placing a listbox on the form and the assigning it to one member like this: `mediaLibrary[0] = listBox1;` In the former case all sorts of properties must be set in code; to ease some of it a FlowLayoutPanel is recommened. (Or asking your teacher)